# apt tools can't resolve host name

Tags: linux, debian, hostname, apt

I am trying to run `apt-get update` from a local virtualbox running Debian to pull packages in from a local apt-repository set up on another server on the local network (over a VPN).

All other tools are perfectly able to resolve the host name of the local server hosting the apt repository. However, when I run `sudo apt-get update` I keep getting the following error message:

```
Ign https://[someserver.com/] dev Release.gpg
Ign https://[someserver.com/] dev Release
Err https://[someserver.com/] dev/main amd64 Packages

Err https://[someserver.com/] dev/main amd64 Packages

Ign https://[someserver.com/] dev/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https://[someserver.com/] dev/main Translation-en
Err https://[someserver.com/] dev/main amd64 Packages
  Couldn't resolve host '[someserver.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://[someserver.com/dists/dev/main/binary-amd64/Packages]/  
    Couldn't resolve host '[someserver.com'

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I ping 'someserver.com', it comes back fine. If I try to retrieve the Packages list via wget on the command line, the retrieval is successful; it seems to be only apt that can't resolve the host name.

Actually I changed someserver.com to google.com for a test, and it returned saying `Couldn't resolve '[google.com'`

btw. Are the square-brackets before the hostname as they appear in the error message  significant at all? I noticed that when i reverted back to using the official public debian repos, there are no square brackets around the hostnames at all in the log messages and that the update completes successfully.

The entry in my sources.list file for the repo is as follows:

```
deb https://username:hex-encoded-password@someserver.com/ dev main
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it resolve the hostname correctly if you remove the username and password from the sources.list linbe?

Comment: Yep it does. But then it returns a 401 error as follows:

Comment: So the username:password specification is conflicting with the hostname, then. The syntax is legal according to the Debian docs (http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository), so maybe the password has a bad character (e.g. password has an '@', and apt is decoding it before parsing). I skipped HTTP authentication when I had to password-protect an APT repo many years back. The SSH method is much more reliable.

Comment: Yes the password does have a couple of special characters in it. Without encoding the password, running apt-get would cause a segmentation fault :D ... and now it seems that even when with encoding there is still a problem, or get the sysadmin to enable access to the repo via SSH as you suggest.

Unless there is nothing else to try, the next step would presumably be to test by changing the password to something without special characters.

Comment: You could try something a bit crazy, like a local tunnel or proxy that then performs the HTTP authentication for you. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527046/proxy-built-with-netcat-not-allowing-http-basic-authentication . I presume that escaping the (unencoded) special password characters (\ or \\ or \\\) doesn't work.

Comment: Brilliant dude! I changed my password to remove all special characters and the pull now finally works.

It didn't occur to me after encoding the password in sources.list that the apt tools might do some funny decoding before trying to process the request.

Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

OK - so the problem was that my password contained a couple of special characters in it, a `[` and something else. I changed my it to a regular alphanumeric value and hey presto, its pulling from the repositories absolutely fine now.

Thanks again to mkfs for his help.